# Write text to file in Python

Tags: python

How to write text to file in Python?

My try:

```
def test(src):
    f = open('test.txt','w')
    f.write("testabc")
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        print s
        f.write(s)

def main ():
    src="/path/"
    test(src)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but it does not work

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: "it does not work"? Describe how it breaks, please.

Comment: Do not write text to my file (`testabc` and `s` variable value)

Comment: Besides the missing `f.close()` and (probably) missing line separators in the output file, it "works" for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `f.close()`

```
.....
for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        print s
        f.write(s)
f.close() # <- add this line
.....
```

Answer (score 6):

Best use a `with` block which will handle the closing of the file for you:

```
def test(src):
    with open('test.txt','w') as f:
        f.write("testabc")
        for item in os.listdir(src):
            s = os.path.join(src, item)
            print s
            f.write(s)
```